# Tablesorter filter and sum issue

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a table with tablesorter, in which I want to have total sums for decimal columns and also to have a possibility to filter data by any column.

It works perfect, when I filter table by decimals, but when I filter it by date, then row with totals disappears.

```js
$($('#incomesTable').tablesorter({
  theme: 'bootstrap',
  sortInitialOrder: "desc",
  widgets: ['math', 'zebra', 'filter'],
  widgetOptions: {
    filter_cssFilter: '',
    filter_childRows: false,
    filter_hideFilters: false,
    filter_ignoreCase: true,
    filter_saveFilters: true,
    filter_searchDelay: 300,
    filter_startsWith: false,
    math_data: 'math',
    // math_ignore: [0, 1],
    math_none: 'N/A',
    math_complete: function($cell, wo, result, value, arry) {
      var txt = '<span class="align-decimal">' +
        result + '</span>';
      if ($cell.attr('data-math') === 'all-sum') {
        return txt + ' (Sum of ' + arry.length + ' cells)';
      }
      return txt;
    },
    math_completed: function(c) {
      console.log('math calculations complete', c.$table.find('[data-math="all-sum"]:first').text());
    },
    math_textAttr: '',
    math_mask: '0.##',
    math_prefix: '',
    math_suffix: '',
    math_event: 'recalculate',
    math_priority: ['row', 'above', 'below', 'col'],
    math_rowFilter: ''
  }
}));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.3/css/theme.bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-1r2gsUynzocV5QbYgEwbcNGYQeQ4jgHUNZLl+PMr6o248376S3f9k8zmXvsKkU06wH0MrmQacKd0BjJ/kWeeng==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.3/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" integrity="sha512-qzgd5cYSZcosqpzpn7zF2ZId8f/8CHmFKZ8j7mU4OUXTNRd5g+ZHBPsgKEwoqxCtdQvExE5LprwwPAgoicguNg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.3/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js" integrity="sha512-dj/9K5GRIEZu+Igm9tC16XPOTz0RdPk9FGxfZxShWf65JJNU2TjbElGjuOo3EhwAJRPhJxwEJ5b+/Ouo+VqZdQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.3/js/widgets/widget-math.min.js" integrity="sha512-9bQAn0y1alBDFoH7VsUSKQd0ilHlbtsGkfjBDIR0iIerF0kvzUp/CfRubUkYT13Ithu0jZ3T+9vBC7FooHwWXQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table id="incomesTable" class="table table-sm table-striped table-hover tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Decimal</th>
      <th>Decimal</th>
      <th>Decimal</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>01.10.2020</td>
      <td>01.10.2020</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td>300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01.11.2020</td>
      <td>01.11.2020</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Total</th>
      <th data-math="col-sum">col-sum</th>
      <th data-math="col-sum">col-sum</th>
      <th data-math="col-sum">col-sum</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ak29tupf/

Comment: It's very hard to help you without seeing any code.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I know, I've got problem with jsfiddle link, but now it's here.

Comment: I've fixed the fiddle link and put all relevant code in the question for you. Please take care to do this in future.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the tablesorter is looking for the calculated values when you perform a filter.

In your example, searching for `10` in the first decimal field shows the calculated row because it's value matches, eg. `110`. However when you search for a date, the calculated cell for that column contain only the word 'Total', so there is no match and the calculated row is hidden.

The quick way to fix this would be to move the calculated row in to a `tfoot` element to exclude it from the filtering:

```html
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Total</th>
    <th data-math="col-sum">col-sum</th>
    <th data-math="col-sum">col-sum</th>
    <th data-math="col-sum">col-sum</th>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/712whmur/)

Alternatively put a class on the `tbody` containing only the calculated row and use the `cssInfoBlock` property of TableSorter to exclude that content from the filtering:

```js
$($('#incomesTable').tablesorter({
  cssInfoBlock: 'calc',
  // other settings...
});
```

```html
<tbody class="calc">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Total</th>
    <th data-math="col-sum">col-sum</th>
    <th data-math="col-sum">col-sum</th>
    <th data-math="col-sum">col-sum</th>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/712whmur/1/)

Comment: No problem, glad to help